# Future not setting default value on load

Tags: flutter, list, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

We are running a Future which should be setting the initial/default at time of load but we cannot seem to get this to work. The default seems to update only state change

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Payment>>(
      future: DatabaseService.getPayments(widget.user!.id),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              const Divider(),
              ListView.separated(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Dismissible(
                        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                        key: Key(snapshot.data![index].cardId!),
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          // Remove the item from the data source.
                          setState(() {
                            snapshot.data!.removeAt(index);
                          });
                        },
                        // Show a red background as the item is swiped away.
                        background: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: const [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.delete_forever_outlined,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 32,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        confirmDismiss:
                            (DismissDirection dismissDirection) async {
                          switch (dismissDirection) {
                            case DismissDirection.endToStart:
                            case DismissDirection.startToEnd:
                              return await _showConfirmationDialog(
                                      context,
                                      'delete',
                                      snapshot.data![index],
                                      widget.user) ==
                                  true;
                            case DismissDirection.horizontal:
                            case DismissDirection.vertical:
                            case DismissDirection.up:
                            case DismissDirection.down:
                            case DismissDirection.none:
                              break;
                          }
                          return false;
                        },
                        child: ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              paymentDefault = snapshot.data![index].cardId;
                              DatabaseService.createDefaultPayment(
                                  context,
                                  snapshot.data![index].cardId,
                                  widget.user!.id);
                            });
                          },
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor:
                                  snapshot.data![index].brand == 'MasterCard'
                                      ? Colors.amber[100]
                                      : Colors.blue[100],
                              radius: 30,
                              child: loadImage(snapshot.data![index].brand)),
                          selected:
                              paymentDefault == snapshot.data![index].cardId,
                          title: Text('•••• ${snapshot.data![index].last4}'),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              'Exp. ${snapshot.data![index].expMonth}/${snapshot.data![0].expYear}'),
                          trailing:
                              paymentDefault == snapshot.data![index].cardId
                                  ? const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green)
                                  : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                        ));
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider(
                      height: 0,
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          );
        }
```

Comment: This is broken: `future: DatabaseService.getPayments(widget.user!.id),` Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Comment: the future works, the problem is getting the initial selected value

Comment: [`initialData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#instance-properties) in the FutureBuilder properties is probably what you are looking for

Comment: @BossNass that’s precisely a symptom of what I pointed out

Answer (score 1):

Use [`initialData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#instance-properties) prop in `FutureBuilder`

> The data that will be used to create the snapshots provided until a non-null future has completed.

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Payment>>(
      initialData: <Your initial Data here>   Here
      future: DatabaseService.getPayments(widget.user!.id),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
         ... 
      }
```

Comment: can this init data make an API call?

Comment: No , use future for that, If you want to show data meanwhile the data is fetched in future use this initial data field